# creating a listed hierarchy of id's

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to have run into a problem and no matter how much I search I cannot find a good way to make it work. What I am trying to accomplish is getting a client list for brokers that are listed on the database. each user has an id and a parent_id that I can reference, the user types are as follows, broker, employer, employee. the issue I'm having is that brokers can be listed as the parent_id of another broker so i never know for sure how many levels deep the hierarchy goes.

here is a small example of the issue im facing:

> USER_ID|PARENT_ID|user type 
>      2   |    1    | broker  
>      3   |    2    | broker  
>      4   |    2    | employer  
>      5   |    3    | broker  
>      6   |    3    | employer  
>      7   |    5    | employer  
>      8   |    5    | employer  
>      9   |    8    | employee

I never can never know exactly how deeply nested the brokers are to run a loop for pulling information from the database. and for what I am currently working on I need to establish the entire hierarchy of the logged in user.  Any help will be very much appreciated, this has had me stumped for the last week...

Comment: Can you expand on what "entire heirachy" refers to? Does that mean every ancestor and descendant of a single user? What are the errors or technical problems you're having?

Comment: Well can i see your weeks work code? And the problem you are facing is unclear.

Comment: yes, what i mean by the entire hierarchy is exactly that. trying to pull every user from the logged in user down. so if the logged in user is a broker i need to find every sub-broker, employer, and employee under them as well as all of the sub-broker's employers and employees, and brokers if they have any.

Comment: all the coding i've tried has not been able to accomplish this, so i wont put all of it here. i was trying different variations of 'foreach' and recursive loops. but to no avail. i made a work around for it to do it in steps by selecting from the database the direct child users beneath the logged in user and making an href to fire off the same query when it is clicked for the userid referenced in the href. however, that means the user then has to click through each user to see those below them in the tree. it's very inconvenient for the user if they have many sub-levels below them.